# Is there a way to get the raw data from a sound in SoundJS for reading custom headers?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, createjs, soundjs

I am using SoundJS from CreateJS and I was wondering, is there anyway I can get the raw (hex) data of an audio playing? I am adding a custom header into the audio file for lip syncing characters but I don't know how to get the audio's raw Hex Data.

I've tried looking in `_playbackResource` but nothing.

```
var instance = playSound(whichTalkie);
console.log(instance._playbackResource);
```

I need the raw audio data. How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you want the raw [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) that is loaded.

There is no official way to do this in SoundJS 1.0 (we are exposing a lot more in 2.0, which you can see in the [in-progress branch in Git](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/tree/2.0)).

However, you can access all the buffers that are loaded using:

```
var plugin = createjs.Sound.activePlugin; // The WebAudioPlugin
var buffer = plugin._audioSources[url];
```

Additionally, there is even more info, including the raw Array Buffer, buried in the load items that SoundJS stores.

```
var loader = plugin._loaders[url];
var buffer = loader.rawResult;
```

Unfortunately there is no clean way to get the buffer from a sound instance.

You listen to the "fileload" event, you can get the src directly from the event:

```
createjs.Sound.on("fileload", handleFileLoad);
  createjs.Sound.registerSound("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1524180/MK21.mp3", "music");
function handleFileLoad(event) {
    var src = event.src;
    // Use whatever approach to get the Array or Audio buffer
}
```

Or get the src from a `play()` call:

```
var inst = createjs.Sound.play("music");
var src = inst.src;
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: The rawResult you've mentioned seemed like what I needed but everytime it would come up as undefined. 

I think the raw AudioBuffer is what I'm looking for. To try to clarify I want to be able to view the audio file's data as text(to where headers can be visible in the file like a WAV has the RIFF header). So that way when CreateJS/SoundJS loads in all ot the talking files I can get their data and find my custom headers that will store custom info.